# Having trouble with my Nema 17 stepper motor and TB6600 Driver, I am using a 12 V adaptor

Tags: driver, step-motor

I have attached an image of my setup.
Code I am using is below

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

# Direction pin from controller
DIR = 10
# Step pin from controller
STEP = 8
# 0/1 used to signify clockwise or counterclockwise.
CW = 1
CCW = 0

# Setup pin layout on PI
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Establish Pins in software
GPIO.setup(DIR, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(STEP, GPIO.OUT)

# Set the first direction you want it to spin
GPIO.output(DIR, CW)

try:
    # Run forever.
    while True:

        """Change Direction: Changing direction requires time to switch. The
        time is dictated by the stepper motor and controller. """
        sleep(1.0)
        # Esablish the direction you want to go
        GPIO.output(DIR,CW)

        # Run for 200 steps. This will change based on how you set you controller
        for x in range(200):

            # Set one coil winding to high
            GPIO.output(STEP,GPIO.HIGH)
            # Allow it to get there.
            sleep(.002) # Dictates how fast stepper motor will run
            # Set coil winding to low
            GPIO.output(STEP,GPIO.LOW)
            sleep(.002)
```

## Dictates how fast stepper motor will run[image]

Comment: So what happened? Did the NEMA 17 guy explode?

Comment: `Having trouble with my Nema 17 stepper motor` ... what trouble?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you have white connected to a Pi ground (pin 14) and grey to GPIO 23 (pin 16).

The code is using BCM numbering and GPIO 8 (pin 24) and GPIO 10  (pin 19).

https://pinout.xyz/

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Joan's observation, I'd advise you to avoid Dupont connections to join cables. Alot of my projects had them as the culprits in not having proper connections.